# How do I perform a group_by in a vector of structs?

Tags: rust

I don't quite understand how to use `group_by` in Rust (if I understand correctly that I need this function).
The example is as abstract as possible.
I have a vec of structs:

```
[
Temp 
 { user_id: 2, username: "test", role_id: 1, role: 123 }, 
Temp 
 { user_id: 2, username: "test", role_id: 2, role: 456 }
]
```

I want to get

```
User { 
 user_id: 2, 
 username: "test",
  roles: [
  Role {
   id: 1,
   role: 123
  },
  … etc
 ]
}
```

Code example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=015ea88d75a16ac943c6ffd763c4f599)):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Temp {
    user_id: i32,
    username: String,
    role_id: i32,
    role: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    username: String,
    roles: Vec<Role>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Role {
    id: i32,
    role: String,
}

fn main() {
    let temps_data = vec![
        Temp {
            user_id: 1,
            username: "test".to_string(),
            role_id: 1,
            role: "test1".to_string(),
        },
        Temp {
            user_id: 1,
            username: "test".to_string(),
            role_id: 2,
            role: "test2".to_string(),
        },
    ];

    // temps_data.group_by(|obj| {
    //     // I don't really understand what should be here
    // })

    // for example, what I want to get
    let result = vec![User {
        id: 1,
        username: "test".to_string(),
        roles: vec![
            Role {
                id: 1,
                role: "test1".to_string(),
            },
            Role {
                id: 2,
                role: "test2".to_string(),
            },
        ],
    }];
}
```

Comment: usually it is better if you add some example on your code, extra points for an [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) link

Comment: [`group_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.group_by) only exists as an experimental method. Were you thinking of this particular method, or do you just want to group a sequence of values by some criteria?

Comment: Initially, during the training, I just solve the SQL N+1 problem, so I don't consider this method rigidly, but in general I'm looking for some elegant solution.

Updated the startpost, added playground.

Comment: The problem is not quite clear to me. What is the key would like to group by? Is it the user id or the name? What should happen if there are `Temp` items with the same user id, but different user names? Will all `Temp` items for the same user be consecutive, or can they occur in random order?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Updated the sample code in the original message. I want to group by several fields of the temporary structure (user_id, username). I want to get a different structure at the output, see the code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do something like this:

```
    let res: Vec<User> = temp_data
        .iter()
        .group_by(|x| (x.user_id, x.username.clone()))
        .into_iter()
        .map(|((id, username), group)| User {
            id, 
            username: username, 
            roles: Some(group.map(|u| Role {id: u.role_id, role: u.role.clone()}).collect()),
        })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", res);

// [User { id: 1, username: "test", roles: Some([Role { id: 1, role: "test1" }, Role { id: 2, role: "test2" }]) }]
```

Here is playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66e1b71bc919ff98e0f100aea3d0351a

Comment: Note that this only works if all entries for the same key are consecutive in the input vec.

Comment: Thanks, Sven, I didn't notice that at first. Still, it must be rather straitforward to do `.sort()` before calling `.group_by()`. Only a simple implementation of `PatialOrd` is needed for `Temp`.

Comment: Thank you for the decision. Sorting is not a problem. Now it has become clearer how to use group_by.

Good luck to everyone!

Comment: Instead of sorting first, I'd personally collect into a hash map. That will preserve linear time complexity, and the code is actually overall shorter and easier than the version based on `group_by()`.